# Won't charge if battery is completely drained

Tags: battery, 7.5

I have a Dell Venue Pro and a Dell 214L0 1400mAh battery.

When the battery is re-charged before being completely drained, things are fine.  However, if the battery is drained, after attaching a charger does not result in a charged battery.  Rather, phone won't turn on and won't charge.

To work around this, I have to remove the battery, wait for a couple of minutes, and re-insert the battery.  Then it will charge as expected.

How can I troubleshoot this and hopefully make this a thing of the past?

Comment: Did you try charging with a PC USB port or the original charger of the phone?

Comment: Either way, actually.

Comment: Are you using the USB cable that came with the phone?  My Nokia Lumia 800 does the same when I use any other cable than the one supplied with the phone.  It also charges at a fraction of the current when it does charge at all with a different cable (ie. when it is not being charged from empty).

Comment: @paranoid Anything special about that cable?  I have about a dozen of these cables, all look the same to me.  How can I tell?

Comment: From my testing, the micro-USB cable that came with my Nokia Lumia 800 is clearly different in some way to the other micro-USB cables I have used with it, which give ten times less charging current, but I do not know why.  This is a pain, as I want to have a cable in my car and at work. (I didn't get any alert as you misspelt my username)

Comment: @paradroid Thanks for a clue, I'll look to see if others have a similar experience. (sorry for misspelling, that was not what I intended)

Answer (score 1):

My Samsung focus had the same problem. I think it is a problem with the firmware on the phone. I exchanged mine out twice, and each phone had the problem.

When I talked to the ATT support rep about it, he told me a few others had the same problem, and basically said it was up to the manufacturer to fix it.

I doubt Dell is going to do anything at this point, so you may be stuck with it. Sorry that i don't have great news, but at least you have a workaround

The only other workaround is to not let it die.

Comment: Imagine a similar problem on the iPhone.  Unsloder, then re-solder the battery.

Answer (score 1):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1007449.html

points to

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=11699369&postcount=10

However, this is just a workaround.  It would be nice to have a fix.

*EDIT* Their advice is my advice, in a different form.  Here's how I'd do it:

1. Remove lid, battery, and charging cable from the phone
2. Press the power-on button, allowing remnants of life to be eked out of the phone's power controller
3. Re-insert the battery and carefully close the back lid
4. Presto, it will charge up

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue and I would pull the battery, put the phone on the charger, the (while it was on) stuff the battery in.  I'm sure this violates some kind of warranty so try at your own risk.