# Is it safe to use an android charger with Windows 8 Phone?

Tags: functionality

I recently have bought and HTC 8s a Windows 8 Phone. Previously I was using a Samsung Galaxy SL 9003 model and I tried using the charger of my Samsung phone with this new HTC phone and it worked !

I wanted to know if is it safe to use this.

As I am planning to keep one charger (the one that came with the HTC box) for home use and my previous android charger for office use.

Please throw some light on this fellas. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - devices which charge by USB are all usually the same voltage and wattage.

Comment: Most have the same voltage and amperage of 5V and 500mA (0.5A). But you should check to make sure that the two chargers have similar outputs. Some high-speed or tablet chargers output a lot more amps.

Comment: As row1 points out - while the voltage output is usually the same, the Ampage may well be different - so do check the charger, too low and it will take a lot longer to charge, too high and you might damage the battery. Also some manufacturers do "interesting" things with their supplied cables such that a completely flat phone won't actually recharge [unless the correct cable/charger combination is used](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/804/520)

Answer (score 4):

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Serial_Bus#Mobile_device_charger_standards):

> As of 14 June 2007, all new mobile phones applying for a license in China are required to be able to use a USB port as a power port for battery charging. This was the first standard to use the convention of shorting D+ and D-.
>
> In September 2007, the Open Mobile Terminal Platform group (a forum of mobile network operators and manufacturers such as Nokia, Samsung, Motorola, Sony Ericsson and LG) announced that its members had agreed on micro-USB as the future common connector for mobile devices.
>
> On 17 February 2009, the GSM Association (GSMA) announced that they had agreed on a standard charger for mobile phones. The standard connector to be adopted by manufacturers including Nokia, Motorola and Samsung is to be the micro-USB connector

As such, you could expect any *mobile phone* USB charger to work for any mobile phone designed since these agreements were made - I admit to having far too many USB phone charges lying around, and have seen no issues charging Nokia devices with HTC chargers and vice-versa.

Generic, third party, "compatible" chargers might be another story, and it would be advisable to check the output current doesn't exceed 500mA.